# Here Geocoding: Unable to search by Canadian postal codes

Tags: here-api

We recently tried to migrate to the new Geocoding api v7 and we're having problem searching by postal code in Canada. Using the previous version of the API, we were receiving proper result but now the service returns nothing.

Here is the url I'm using:

[https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apikey={myKey}&q=g1r4w4](https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apikey=%7BmyKey%7D&q=g1r4w4)

The return is empty `{"items":[]}`

Previously, we used this URL:

[https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id={appId}&app_code={appCode}&searchtext=g1r4w4](https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=%7BappId%7D&app_code=%7BappCode%7D&searchtext=g1r4w4)

This call properly returned the result associated with the postal code.

`{"Response":{"MetaInfo":{"Timestamp":"2020-11-19T12:43:47.455+0000"},"View":[{"_type":"SearchResultsViewType","ViewId":0,"Result":[{"Relevance":1.0,"MatchLevel":"postalCode","MatchQuality":{"PostalCode":1.0},"Location":{"LocationId":"NT_yQ4FsR2UeO4wRSzRRMGA0B","LocationType":"point","DisplayPosition":{"Latitude":46.80349,"Longitude":-71.22871},"NavigationPosition":[{"Latitude":46.80349,"Longitude":-71.22871}],"MapView":{"TopLeft":{"Latitude":46.81698,"Longitude":-71.24842},"BottomRight":{"Latitude":46.79,"Longitude":-71.209}},"Address":{"Label":"G1R 4W4, Québec, QC, Canada","Country":"CAN","State":"QC","County":"Québec","City":"Québec","PostalCode":"G1R 4W4","AdditionalData":[{"value":"Canada","key":"CountryName"},{"value":"Québec","key":"StateName"},{"value":"Québec","key":"CountyName"}]}}}]}]}}`

Is there anything I'm missing here to make it work?

Comment: A qualified query with a sub-parameter might work. Something like https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apikey={myKey}&qq=postalCode=g1r+4w4

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that there have been some improvements and your request is showing meanwhile the following response:

{

```
"items": [
    {
        "title": "G1R 4W4 Avenue de Bourlamaque, Québec, QC, Canada",
        "id": "here:af:streetsection:uBCczpZNke89jNSCVVy-WA:EAMyB2cxcnw0dzQ",
        "resultType": "postalCodePoint",
        "address": {
            "label": "G1R 4W4 Avenue de Bourlamaque, Québec, QC, Canada",
            "countryCode": "CAN",
            "countryName": "Canada",
            "stateCode": "QC",
            "state": "Québec",
            "county": "Québec",
            "city": "Québec",
            "district": "Vieux-Québec-Montcalm",
            "street": "Avenue de Bourlamaque",
            "postalCode": "G1R 4W4"
        },
        "position": {
            "lat": 46.80349,
            "lng": -71.22871
        },
        "access": [
            {
                "lat": 46.80349,
                "lng": -71.22871
            }
        ],
        "mapView": {
            "west": -71.23035,
            "south": 46.80237,
            "east": -71.22707,
            "north": 46.80461
        },
        "scoring": {
            "queryScore": 1.0,
            "fieldScore": {
                "postalCode": 1.0
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}